# How can I generate entity classes from database without using mapping files?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have db tables and hibernate configuration file. Thing is I want to generate entity classes (which are using annotations not mapping files) from these tables. I am using Netbeans and there is an option "Create Hibernate Mapping files and POJOs from database", but I don't want to deal with mapping files, instead of them I want to use annotations. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is using eclipse : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/